# Made a simple code in python on VS code but got this error and the terminal would not open

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6B2W.png)

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 2).

Comment: Unfortunately, that is quite a broad error, so it is difficult to suggest possible reasons. Are you running your script via the "run" menu?

Comment: the question needs sufficient background and code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is it valid to downgrade vscode?